# Why URL parameter is not working rewrite URL htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get blog details page with rewriting URL

like this ->>
[www.sitename.com/blog/test-post](http://www.sitename.com/blog/test-post)

My code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+) details.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is , it is coming the details page, but the blog list page

[www.sitename.com/blog/](http://www.sitename.com/blog/)

also redirecting to blog details page. how can i avoid this. i also tried with number code like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+) details.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

the url with number parameter works fine, but letters is not working. how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip files and directories from your rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . details.php [L]

</IfModule>
```